# Add class to pagination previous/next button in view Drupal 8

Tags: views

how to add class to pagination previous/next/first/last button in view Drupal 8. Also how to show

First last next previous button default as default is show next/last

Answer (score 1):

One way to add a class to Views pagers is to add the class to the template.

You can copy the template file from `/web/core/modules/views/templates/` into your theme's templates folder and add the classes however you like.

The mini pager template is `views-mini-pager.html.twig`.